Reviving the weekly topic challange?
Why not revive the weekly topic challange ?
The general Question could be asked directly on the forum (contrary to being posted on meta).
At the end of the week all the relevant answers could be collected and posted as an answer to this question. 
As I see it not many users lookt at meta. Despite being crude it might be wise to run the weekly challange via the main forum rather than meta.
